# Xamarin webview on IOS not passing authorization header for images

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to load a webpage in Xamarin Forms IOS in a webview from a secure web service. I've managed to get the initial html loaded and can successfully pass the bearer token in the Authorization header for the first request. However when the webview tries to load the images referenced in the html the bearer token is not passed so the images are not loaded. I'm using a custom renderer in the IOS project.

I've based my code on this github example https://github.com/albertoms/xamarin-webview-with-custom-headers

```
public class SecureWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<SecureWebView, UIWebView>
{
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == "Source")
        {
            var webView = Control as UIWebView;
            UrlWebViewSource source = Element.Source as UrlWebViewSource;
            if (source != null)
            {
                var headerKey = new NSString("Authorization");
                var headerValue = new NSString($"Bearer {Element.AuthorizationToken}");
                var dictionary = new NSDictionary(headerKey, headerValue);

                var webRequest = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl(source.Url));
                webRequest.Headers = dictionary;

                Control.LoadRequest(webRequest);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SecureWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var webView = Control as UIWebView;

        if (webView == null)
        {
            webView = new UIWebView();
            webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
            webView.ShouldStartLoad = ShouldStartLoad;

            SetNativeControl(webView);
        }
        else
        {
            webView.ShouldStartLoad = ShouldStartLoad;
        }

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {

            var headerKey = new NSString("Authorization");
            var headerValue = new NSString($"Bearer {Element.AuthorizationToken}");
            var dictionary = new NSDictionary(headerKey, headerValue);

            UrlWebViewSource source = (Xamarin.Forms.UrlWebViewSource)Element.Source;
            var webRequest = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl(source.Url));
            webRequest.Headers = dictionary;

            Control.ShouldStartLoad = ShouldStartLoad;
            Control.LoadRequest(webRequest);
        }

    }

    public bool ShouldStartLoad(UIWebView webView,
                                          NSUrlRequest request,
                                          UIWebViewNavigationType navigationType)
    {
        if (!request.Headers.ContainsKey(new NSString("Authorization")))
        {
            request.Headers.SetValueForKey((NSString)("Bearer " + Element.AuthorizationToken), (NSString)"Authorization");
        }


        return true;
    }
}
```

I've tried putting in breakpoints everywhere but it never breaks when trying to load the images, only when it first loads the html. I've inspected the headers in fiddler and the Authorization header is not there when it tries to load the images. Also when I turn off authentication in the web service the images load correctly. Any ideas on how I can get the Authorization header to be attached to the image requests?

Comment: I tried this site's code and it has exactly the same issue. The HTML loads correctly but when it tries to load images referenced in the HTML it doesn't work. ShouldStartLoad only fires when the page is loaded, not when images are loaded so the authorization header never get set for the image requests.

Comment: Thats really interesting...i could think of two possible solutions to this 1.Create your custom by inheriting NSURLProtocol. 2. This might be the simplest and quick by using NSHttpCookieStorage...something like this NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.SetCookie (
    new NSHttpCookie ("HeaderName", "HeaderValue", "/", "hostname.example.com")
);